# can I use DNS with private NAT addresses?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nat, ipv4

I want to build a service that dynamically creates VMs and assigns each VM a public DNS record which could be a full domain or a subdomain. Assume the VMS all live on a single host. The VMs will have a mix of TCP or UDP exposed services running on them, using various ports. The host has one public ip address.

Can I use NAT to do anything with routing the Domains to the VM's or do I need more public ip addresses for this setup?

How do other virtualized hosting companies do this? do they have more ip blocks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I use NAT to do anything with routing the Domains

No, NAT is not aware of DNS.

> Do I need more public ip addresses

You need one IP per server IP:Port tuple. If everything is running on different ports then you could conceivable use the same IP for everything. Just a reminder, IP knows nothing about DNS, and DNS knows nothing about service ports (unless the application specifically supports SRV records, which is crazy rare for reasons unbeknownst to me).

> How do other virtualized hosting companies do this? do they have more ip blocks?

Either the application is DNS aware (like HTTP, which uses application layer headers; or TLS, which uses SNI which is like a header) or they use separate IPs per destination.